# VS Code debugger doesn't step into

Tags: visual-studio-code

I didn't find an answer to this problem with nodejs:
I have a breakpoint in index.js at the line require("./test). When I click the Step Into button, the debugger doesn't jump to the test file like it should, but instead runs and displays the result immediately. I don't have any expressions for watching.

P.S https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15253 - this issue from github is the same as mine
Kind regards

Comment: you have to call function in the `test.js` file

Comment: Only very loosely related: [How to quickly step into require() call while debugging Node.js with Chrome DevTools](/q/61519368). Also, if you could provide a gif screen recording, that would be nice :)

Comment: @rioV8 nope, same result.This is screen recording https://streamable.com/x2gn09

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem ,tried to reproduce on my personal laptop and the debugger was worked fine(node v18.14.0). On my work laptop node version were 19.16.0.I switched to 18.14.0 and the debugger starts work as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).